# How to Group Font Weights

Tags: fonts, adobe-creative-suite, font-weight

I have a pet peeve when I download free fonts on the web and once they install all the weights are their separate font. Is there a way I can put them under one font that way I can just change the weights in the Weights tab. I'm talking about Adobe Creative Cloud, if that matters.

Also, is there a way I can categorize the fonts I've download instead of them being mixed up with the computer's standard fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but I always liked [MainType](http://www.high-logic.com/font-manager/maintype.html) & [FontExplorer X Pro](https://www.fontexplorerx.com/)

My favorite feature on maintype is Font Group, I don't know if the newer version of FontExplorerX has it.

---

Another thing I do to keep my fonts recognised is, I write them down, What are the best fonts for print? for web? for apps? I select 5 to 10 fonts (free or paid) and choose with the team which one is the best for  of project