# How to rename individual fonts so Photoshop recognizes them as a font family?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I downloaded some weight variations of a single font (ex. light, regular, bold, etc.) but the naming conventions used weren't consistent (ex. Font Light, Font LLight, etc.). I think Photoshop reads them as separate fonts because the naming within the file isn't consistent so I'm unable to simply change the font in the "font weight" dropdown. Instead I have to search for the name of the specific font weight every time I need to make a change, which becomes tedious.

Is there an easy way to fix the font file names so they appear as a complete font family in Photoshop?

Comment: that's how Photoshop works, this is not really a design question.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-package-all-faces-of-a-font-into-one-family-file-mac or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55949/how-to-group-font-weights or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81468/font-organisation or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83374/how-to-generate-one-font-file-consisting-of-multiple-font-weights-i-e-multiple or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35874/how-to-link-font-styles-in-windows

Comment: @Luciano: it's not just Photoshop that would have a problem with such fonts. No matter how smart the software, some font designers literally *don't seem to care* to use their design software properly.

Comment: This community is the go-to place for font-related questions! The problem described is just a "configuration" matter for the fonts, something a proficient type designer must be aware of — even if it is a little technical. **Just because it does not fall in the field of expertise of the moderators (or users with vetting rights), it does NOT mean it is not in the field of expertise of anyone on this community.**

Comment: The Python "fontools" package contains a command line tool called ttx. This converts ttf/otf files into an xml file with the name table near the top. Extra entries can be added to this, that when it converts it back to a proper font file, it will show up as whatever family you want it to. Create a namerecord tag with nameID=16 for the family, and another with nameID=17 for the type. Existing namerecord tags should remain as-is. I could provide a more comprehensive answer if the question was unclosed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using programs that edit fonts an example is [Fontlab](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-vi/).

Comment: That does not really sound like an easy way.